# Link PahoMqttCpp as a static library in CMake using Conan

Tags: c++, cmake, paho, conan

I am working on a C++ web framework, `oatpp` to create REST APIs. Using the [oatpp-starter](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp-starter) project where the `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(project_name my-project) ## rename your project here

project(${project_name})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(${project_name}-lib
        src/AppComponent.hpp
        src/controller/MyController.cpp
        src/controller/MyController.hpp
        src/dto/DTOs.hpp
)

## link libs

find_package(oatpp 1.2.5 REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-lib
        PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp
        PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp-test
)

target_include_directories(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC src)

## add executables

add_executable(${project_name}-exe
        src/App.cpp
        test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp)
target_link_libraries(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)

add_executable(${project_name}-test
        test/tests.cpp
        test/app/TestComponent.hpp
        test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp
        test/MyControllerTest.cpp
        test/MyControllerTest.hpp
)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)

set_target_properties(${project_name}-lib ${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-test PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 11
        CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)

enable_testing()
add_test(project-tests ${project_name}-test)
```

The executable I get after compiling this code runs successfully inside a container with same architecture. But when I add `paho-mqtt` library to the project, the executable does't run on the container because `the shared library libpaho-mqttcpp3.so.1 not found: No such file or directory` error.

I am adding the library using this configuration:
Updated `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(project_name my-project) ## rename your project here

project(${project_name})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(${project_name}-lib
        src/AppComponent.hpp
        src/controller/MyController.cpp
        src/controller/MyController.hpp
        src/dto/DTOs.hpp
)

## link libs

find_package(oatpp 1.2.5 REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-lib
        PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp
        PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp-test
)


## conan
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

target_include_directories(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC src)

## add executables

add_executable(${project_name}-exe
        src/App.cpp
        test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp)
target_link_libraries(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib ${CONAN_LIBS})
add_dependencies(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)

add_executable(${project_name}-test
        test/tests.cpp
        test/app/TestComponent.hpp
        test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp
        test/MyControllerTest.cpp
        test/MyControllerTest.hpp
)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib ${CONAN_LIBS})
add_dependencies(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)

set_target_properties(${project_name}-lib ${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-test PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 11
        CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)

enable_testing()
add_test(project-tests ${project_name}-test)
```

Here's the `conanfile.txt`

```
[requires]
paho-mqtt-cpp/1.2.0     # MQTT Client

[generators]
cmake
```

How to configure CMake to use Conan's downloaded PahoMqttCpp library to build a standalone project executable (using static library)

Comment: please, share your conanfile and entire log too. Only reading your symptoms, it seems like oatpp is installed, but impossible to say if it took the library directory from system or from conan.

Comment: I am posting my conanfile and answering my solution since I figured it out. TLDR; instead of installing oatpp, and using conan for mqtt client, configure cmake to use conan & then use libraries provided by conan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what was happening:
I configured `CMakeLists.txt` incorrectly to integrate with `conan`. Since I had `paho-mqtt-cpp` installed beforehand, the program was linking to installed libraries instead of those provided by conan.

This `CMakeLists.txt` works for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(PROJECT_NAME my-awesome-project)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

############################### CONAN SETUP BEGIN ##########################################
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
    message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
    file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/v0.9/conan.cmake"
            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
endif()
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)
conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE conanfile.txt BASIC_SETUP)
############################### CONAN SETUP END ############################################

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib
        # controllers
        src/controller/StaticController.hpp

        # db
        src/db/DemoDb.hpp

        # mqtt
        src/mqtt/MqttCoroutine.hpp
        src/mqtt/MqttClient.hpp

        # dto
        src/dto/PageDto.hpp
        src/dto/StatusDto.hpp
        src/dto/DemoDto.hpp

        # services
        src/service/DemoService.cpp
        src/service/DemoService.hpp

        # base
        src/AppComponent.hpp
        src/DatabaseComponent.hpp
        src/ErrorHandler.cpp
        src/ErrorHandler.hpp)

## include directories
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib PUBLIC src)


add_definitions(
        ## SQLite database file
        -DDATABASE_FILE="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sql/db.sqlite"

        ## SQLite database test file
        -DTESTDATABASE_FILE="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sql/test-db.sqlite"

        ## Path to database migration scripts
        -DDATABASE_MIGRATIONS="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sql"

        ## my-awesome-project Service
        -DHOST="0.0.0.0"
        -DPORT=8080

        ## MQTT Broker
        -DMQTT_BROKER_URL="tcp://127.0.0.1:1883"
)

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES Linux)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib INTERFACE Threads::Threads ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
endif()

## add executables
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}-exe src/App.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-exe ${PROJECT_NAME}-lib ${CONAN_LIBS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}-test
        test/tests.cpp
        test/app/TestClient.hpp
        test/app/TestDatabaseComponent.hpp
        test/app/TestComponent.hpp
        test/DeviceControllerTest.hpp
        test/DeviceControllerTest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME}-lib ${CONAN_LIBS})

enable_testing()
add_test(e2e-tests ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
```

Along with this `conanfile.txt`

```
[requires]
oatpp/1.2.5             # REST library
oatpp-sqlite/1.2.5      # SQLite3 plugin
paho-mqtt-cpp/1.2.0     # MQTT Client

[generators]
cmake
```

Just use regular `cmake` command to generate `Makefile`. Then run `make` to get the executable.